# What is the election process of Router ID in OSPF?

Tags: routing, router, protocol-theory, ospf

I am a little confused on the process OSPF uses to select the Router ID. Is following correct for the selection of the router ID in OSPF?

1. Manual configuration
2. Highest IP address on a loopback interface
3. Highest IP address on a non-loopback interface

Comment: That is correct, at least for Cisco routers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Amazingly enough, for something so important to OSPF, the RFC doesn't define the Router ID selection process. A Router ID is simply a 32-bit number, and the implementation of it may vary from vendor to vendor. What you describe is how Cisco does it, but other vendors are free to do it any way they want. In fact, the example in [*RFC 2328, OSPF Version 2*](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2328.txt) is using the smallest IP address (see below), not the largest as Cisco does.

The Router ID *is not* an IPv4 address, and you can use a Router ID that is any 32-bit number, even if it looks like a bad IPv4 address.

> Router ID
>
> A 32-bit number that uniquely identifies this router in the
>   AS. One possible implementation strategy would be to use the **smallest
>   IP interface address** belonging to the router. If a router's OSPF
>   Router ID is changed, the router's OSPF software should be restarted
>   before the new Router ID takes effect.  In this case the router should
>   flush its self-originated LSAs from the routing domain (see Section
>   14.1) before restarting, or they will persist for up to MaxAge minutes.

Answer (score 0):

OSPF Router-ID selection happens in the below order.

1. Manually configure a 32-bit Router-ID.
2. Highest IP of the loop back interface, if 1 is not configured.
3. Highest IP of any active interface,if 1 & 2 has not configured.

Comment: That is only for Cisco devices. The question is not specific to Cisco, so the answer could actually be something else for a different vendor.